taskbar issue after last update 24.04 LTS desktop
I am using Ubuntu LTS on my laptop and I upgraded to 24.04.01 LTS in October.
After last reboot in yesterday my taskbar was weird state like in following screenshot.

When I press the Windows key in my keyboard I could see original taskbar(bottom of the second picture). Before the reboot I am using this taskbar. I tried many things including reboot but no progress.

How can I fix this problem and then use my original taskbar again?
Ubuntu and kernel release info as following lines
msuluhan@executor:~$ uname -a
Linux executor 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 21:40:26 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
msuluhan@executor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
msuluhan@executor:~$ 

Best regards
msuluhan

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt autopurge
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean;
applied and then reboot, fixed the problem

not fixed :(
The problem occurs again when the screen saver is activated.

Not enough info. What desktop? Configured how? With some extensions? If so, what? What screensaver?

Hello @Liam
I am using default desktop,
I installed dash to panel, gpaste and show desktop icon extension while I was running 22.04 LTS. After upgrade there was no problem
I did not change anything recently
This problem has started yesterday

You must explicitly spell things like this out for us. We are not psychic: we do not know how you have customised your installation unless you tell us. As stock GNOME does not have a taskbar, so all we know is that it is not stock.

Since you seem to have extensively customised your desktop with a number of extensions, my suggestion is this:

Remove all extensions. (Either use the website or install an extensions manager; there are several).

Reboot

Reinstall new copies of the extensions you want from  https://extensions.gnome.org/


In my experience, I generally find that extensions will not survive an OS upgrade intact. This is one of the many things I do not like about GNOME.

Hello @Liam
Applied your recommendation but not helped, dock and panel/taskbar is not working properly
Reinstalled all gnome packages again

Hello @Liam
Problem related with extension manager and/or extensions
When I disabled extension manager there is no problem

You are not clear. Does this mean it is now fixed? What "extension manager" do you mean and what did you disable, how? You are not giving nearly enough info in your replies and you will just make people angry this way. ALWAYS give full info: names, versions, add-ons, source, what you did, how you did it.
